# Has anyone come across the word 'subscrub' or 'sub-scrub'?

Tags: meaning

I was at a Scottish boarding school (long since closed) and each table in the refectory had six boys.  The most senior boy was called 'the divider; the second 'the sub-divider; the third was called 'the subscrub' (perhaps hyphenated).  On the other side of the table were 'the tea man'; 'second lowest' and 'lowest'.  The other five names are self explanatory but 'subscrub' has always been a puzzle to everyone.

Some recent research has found no dictionary relevant definition but I have found some usage in old newspapers and a couple of novels. In one 1840 newspaper report, an article commenting on the goings-on in parliament refers to 'the sub-scrub or under secretary'.  The other examples suggest a stand-in or substitute sometimes though a stooge.
I have looked at 'scrub' on this site and others but if it is a derogatory term that would imply the more senior boys are the same and there were three more junior boys at each table.  Each boy had a function or duties except the subscrub.
Any assistance would be welcome.

Comment: I wonder if he was originally called 'the sub-sub-divider' and if, shortened to 'sub-sub', he then became 'subscrub'.

Comment: *Scrub*: informal "An insignificant or contemptible person." (Lexico) whence subscrub, maybe? Also, *subscrub* (sailing): a scrub used to clean the hull, whence one detailed to scrub.